# Get a database value in QWeb PDF report (Odoo 10)

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I would like to retrieve a config parameter from database in a custom QWeb Report.

What shall I do?

Specifically, I want to get the equivalent (in the model):

```py
self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('my_param', '')
```

Could someone highlight where to start?

---

As additional information, the report I am trying to use inherits report.minimal_layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <data>

        <template id="report_saleorder_css" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
            <xpath expr="html/head/*[position() = last()]" position="after">
                <style>
                    body {
                        color: <t t-esc="color"/>;
                    }

                </style>
            </xpath>
        </template>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

And this is the custom render function I have tried:

```py
class CustomReport(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.mymodule.report_saleorder_css'
    @api.model
    def render_html(self, data=None):
        report_obj = self.env['report']
        report = report_obj._get_report_from_name('mymodule.report_saleorder_css')
        docargs = {
            'doc_ids': self._ids,
            'doc_model': report.model,
            'docs': self,
            'color': 'red'
        }
        return report_obj.render('mymodule.report_saleorder_css', docargs)
```

without success

Answer (score 1):

In simple word you want to retrieve a config parameter whenever you print qweb report.

we can not directly use self.env in qweb report, but we can call a function which do that operation and return config parameter value. To do that first create python function in your model.

```
@api.model
def get_system_para(self):
    para_value = self.env['ir.config_parameter'].get_param('web.base.url','')
    return para_value
```

Now call this function in your qweb report

```
<span t-esc="docs.get_system_para()"/>
```

Comment: If I try that, I get: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_system_param'. I added the method to sale.order, which is the model used in the qweb pdf report. I can use doc.get_system_param when in the main template, but I can't retrieve docs.get_system_param in the specific template I shared (which inherits report.minimal_layout)

Comment: its get_system_para() not get_system_param and do bracket because its method not field

Comment: I used get_system_param because I named it get_system_param. And I used brackets. It is not a typo, it does not work in this specific case.

Comment: Will post full example tomorrow

Comment: That would be extrmely appreciated. Please ensure to use a report inherited from report.minimal_layout, as I start to suspect that point is relevant (I have been working 4 days with this issue). Below template shall be enough to visually check if the variable is recovered or not in the template.

Comment: <template id="report_saleorder_css" inherit_id="report.minimal_layout">
            <xpath expr="//head" position="inside">
                <span>XXXX</span><span><t t-esc="color"/></span><span>YYYY</span>
            </xpath>
        </template>

Comment: why you want to inherit report.minimal_layout ?

Comment: To add custom css

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the value beforehand and pass it to your template for usage.

You can do this by defining your own parser for your report, check the [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/reference/reports.html).

See under Custom Reports on how you can create your own parser (Python class) and how you can use the docargs. Basically within the `render_html` method you search for your value, insert it on docargs and then pass it on the `render` method. Then you can use it from your template like:
`<t t-esc="my_param" />`

Comment: Thanks, I am trying that without success, any quick check on the parser I am using and the specific template I am trying to parse would be welcomed.

Comment: Make sure your `render_html` method is working first by inserting a print statement. Also, from what I am aware you cannot put CSS on the <head> of your document, move them on the body or use another template to inject them. This can show you how:http://www.surekhatech.com/blog/apply-css-from-external-file-in-odoo-qweb-reports

Comment: George, that is exactly what I am doing, instead of using link you can also embbed it with <style></style>. And it is definitively in the <head> section of the document (check the xpath expression in the example you provide). My only issue is to be able to put a variable into that template (exactly the same template you just shared).

Comment: If I add a print statement in the render_html function, where shall that print output appear? Thanks

Comment: @usk70 the print output should be shown on the server logs

Comment: Then it is not being executed.